# Can't access elements in shadow DOM

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have the following simple python code:

```
login_url = 'https://sso-login.revelup.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(login_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(7)
test_var = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "html")
driver.quit()
```

However I get the following error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="html"]"}`

Note that I am really trying to get the shadow content from the shadow DOM (the input field). However, as you can see from `test_var` (illustration purposes only), I for some reason can't even get the html element.

**The ideal answer im looking for is to grab the input element with id "instance" that's nested in the shadow dom (ie the text field you see).**

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me for anyone that comes across the same problem:

```py
# Execute JavaScript to get the shadow root
shadow_root_script = "return document.querySelector('#shadow-root-wrapper').shadowRoot"
shadow_root = driver.execute_script(shadow_root_script)

# Find an element within the shadow root using CSS Selector
element_in_shadow_dom = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.the_css_selector')
```

**To get shadow root script, you need the JS path (Chrome)**: inspect the element -> right click, "copy" (in the html structure) -> "copy JS path". Now, remove everything after shadowRoot, replace double quotes with single quotes, and prepend with return.

**To get the css selector (only works with a selector)(Chrome)**: inspect -> click on element in the html -> right click and "copy selector" on any css selector that looks right.

Answer (score 0):

To access elements inside a shadow DOM using Selenium, you can use a bit of JavaScript.

1. **Load the Web Page:**
   Open the webpage where the element is located.

   ```py
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   login_url = 'https://sso-login.revelup.com'
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.get(login_url)
   ```
2. **Wait for the Page to Load:**
   Allow some time for the page to fully load.

   ```py
   driver.implicitly_wait(7)
   ```
3. **Find the Shadow Host Element:**
   Identify the element that hosts the shadow DOM. Replace `'your-shadow-host-selector'` with the actual CSS selector of this element.

   ```py
   shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'your-shadow-host-selector')
   ```
4. **Access the Shadow DOM using JavaScript:**
   Execute a script to get access to the shadow DOM.

   ```py
   shadow_root_script = "return arguments[0].shadowRoot"
   shadow_root = driver.execute_script(shadow_root_script, shadow_host)
   ```
5. **Find the Input Element inside the Shadow DOM:**
   Locate the input element within the shadow DOM using its ID, in this case, 'instance'.

   ```py
   input_element = shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, 'instance')
   ```
6. **Interact with the Input Element:**
   Perform actions on the input element, such as typing some text.

   ```py
   input_element.send_keys('your_text_here')
   ```
7. **Close the Browser:**
   Once you're done, close the browser.

   ```py
   driver.quit()
   ```

Make sure to replace `'your-shadow-host-selector'` with the correct CSS selector for the element that contains the shadow DOM. If you have access to the HTML structure of the page, you can inspect it to find the appropriate selector.